# Category Theory: Functors as Diagrams

Tags: category-theory

I have began classes on Category Theory, I do not understand the concept of '***functors as diagrams***' the book I am using is Category Theory and Applications by Marco Grandis.
I have been asked to prove the following statements:

1. Every functor defined on a preordered set $S$ is automatically a commutative diagram.
2. A functor $1 \longrightarrow C$ amounts to an object of $C$ while a functor $2 \longrightarrow C$ amounts to a morphism of C.
3. A functor $X : (\mathbb{N},\leq) \to C$ defined on the ordered set of natural numbers (i.e. the ordinal $\omega$), amounts to a sequence of consecutive morphisms of $C$
   \begin{equation*}
     X_0 \longrightarrow X_1 \longrightarrow X_2 \longrightarrow \dots \longrightarrow X_n \longrightarrow \dots
    \end{equation*}

   while the functor $X : (\mathbb{N},+)\to C$, defined on the additive monoid of natural numbers, amounts to an endomorphism $u_1 : X_* \to X_*$ $(\text{and its powers} \quad u_n=(u_1)^n$, including $u_0=id(X_*))$

Comment: For (1), I am not sure what the formal definition of a commuting diagram is in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea to understand diagrams as functors is that we are associating some sort of map (the functor) with its image (the visual diagram).

As you can read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory)), a diagram in category $C$ is a covariant functor $D:J \rightarrow C$ where $J$ is called an index category. It doesn't really matter what the objects and arrows in $J$ are. Instead it is the connectivity that is important. $D$ associated objects and arrows in $J$ with those in $C$ so that the relationships are preserved. You might find this [blog link](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/a-diagram-is-a-functor) with nice images helpful.

In statement 2, $1$ is the category with a single object and a single arrow. What is the possible image of the functor $1\rightarrow C$? Similar thinking is useful to decode $2 \rightarrow C$ where $2$ is the category $\bullet \rightarrow \bullet$.

Build upon this idea in statement 3. What does the category $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ look like? Then what is the possible image of a functor $X:(\mathbb{N}, \le)\rightarrow C$ look like? For the case involving $(\mathbb{N},+)$, think carefully about how a monoid is understood as a category.

Comment: I quiet understand statement 2 now. I am still lost on statement 3.

Comment: @S.Marco A category $P$ that is a preorder has at most one arrow $p\rightarrow p'$ between objects $p$ and $p'$. Define a binary relation $\le$ such that $p\le p' \iff p \rightarrow p'$. Can you draw a diagram of the category $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$? For the second half of statement 3, do you understand a monoid as a category?